# Cluster networkx graph with sklearn produces unexpected results

Tags: python, clustering, graph, networkx, scikit-learn

I have an interconnected weighted graph. The graph is a representation of a Multilinestring connecting points. See the visualisation in QGIS:

[image]

So from each point I know how much it costs to go to every other point. This information I compute from a Shapefile called "CostShape" to a graph in networkx. I use then this command to produce a numpy array:

```
    matrix = nx.to_numpy_matrix(graph)
```

The result looks as follows:

```
[[0.00000000e+00 2.36988656e+01 1.67140574e+04 ... 5.42805416e+02
5.66551990e+02 2.80353597e+04] 
[2.36988656e+01 0.00000000e+00 1.66903585e+04 ... 5.66504281e+02
5.90250855e+02 2.80590586e+04]
[1.67140574e+04 1.66903585e+04 0.00000000e+00 ... 1.72568628e+04
1.72806093e+04 4.47494171e+04]
...
[5.42805416e+02 5.66504281e+02 1.72568628e+04 ... 0.00000000e+00
2.37465741e+01 2.74925543e+04]
[5.66551990e+02 5.90250855e+02 1.72806093e+04 ... 2.37465741e+01
0.00000000e+00 2.74688077e+04]
[2.80353597e+04 2.80590586e+04 4.47494171e+04 ... 2.74925543e+04
2.74688077e+04 0.00000000e+00]]
```

What already is annoying that I am loosing the names of the node in the graph, but I assume that the order stays the same. I proceed then with the clustering of this Numpy matrix and feed the labels back into the "GraphShape":

```
labeler = KMeans()
labeler.fit(matrix)
for (row, label) in enumerate(labeler.labels_):
    GraphShape.at[row, 'costcluster'] = label
GraphShape.to_file('graphShape.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

The result is the image below this text block and it is everything else but clusters. I tried many different cluster methods and none of them produce the things that I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I would start by verifying if your assumption about the order in your matrix is actually correct?

Comment: thats a good point. any idea how to do that?

Comment: What do you precisely expect? Do you want to cluster the point "by" what? And what exactly are your costs? Just to be sure I understood... Maybe what you want to compute is your graph [centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality). After that, you may be able to interpolate along each of its edges to have "continuous" values, and finally get back this values to the points.

Comment: I extended my answer with another possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to cluster the points with a fixed threshold:

```
clusterThreshold = 1000
clusterNumber = 0
cluster = {}

for pt in range(len(GraphShape)):
    firstpt = list(GraphShape.at[pt, 'geometry'].coords)[0]
    notInClusterYet = True
    # check if point is already somewhere in the dict. if so this cluster value is taken
    for key in cluster.keys():
        if firstpt in cluster[key]:
            notInClusterYet = False
            clusterOfFirstPt = key
            break
    # if not already in the clusterdict, a new clusternumber is registered
    if notInClusterYet:
        clusterNumber += 1
        cluster[clusterNumber] = [firstpt]
        clusterOfFirstPt = clusterNumber
    for spt in range(pt + 1, len(GraphShape)):
        secondpt = list(GraphShape.at[spt, 'geometry'].coords)[0]
        weight, shortestpath = nx.single_source_dijkstra(graph, firstpt, secondpt)
        print(weight)
        if weight < clusterThreshold:
            coordinatelist = cluster[clusterOfFirstPt]
            coordinatelist.append(secondpt)
            cluster[clusterOfFirstPt] = coordinatelist
finished = False
while not finished:
    finished = True
    for key in cluster.keys():
        for coordinate in cluster[key]:
            for subkey in cluster.keys():
                if subkey == key:
                    continue
                for subCoordinate in cluster[subkey]:
                    if subCoordinate == coordinate:
                        newcoordinates = cluster[subkey] + cluster[key]
                        cluster[key] = newcoordinates
                        del cluster[subkey]
                        finished = False
                        break
                if not finished:
                    break
            if not finished:
                break
        if not finished:
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to replicate your setup as best as I could. I downloaded a juncture of two winding secondary highways from OpenStreetMap, loaded them into GeoPandas in Python. For *every* pair of points I computed the physical distance between the two points and used this as edge weight. (So I have a complete graph, a graph with an edge between any two nodes. I had 208 points. This calculation took some 15-20 sec.) Then I conducted the clustering according to your recipe. I loaded the result into QGIS and when I plot it, the clusters look how I expected them.

[image: road juncture]

This led me to suspect that perhaps you were displaying your data wrong in QGIS, although I couldn't easily replicate a random colour distribution. In the Layer Styling, you have to categorise according to the variable `costcluster`. If you categorise according to e.g. point `id`, then it can look very random.

[image: QGIS Layer Styling]

I don't know the edge or weight structure of your graph. But I realised that it can also be the source of the problem. I tested it with two other graphs derived from the same data. In the case when I only ever enter edges with the physical distance into the graph for *pairs of points* which are adjacent (consecutive) in any *way*, the output is rather random.

The reason is clear: all rows of the `matrix` are dissimilar. The clustering tries more or less to put every node into a separate class. As I observe, if I make `n` classes, then I get `n-1` classes with one or at most two nodes in each and all remaining nodes are in one class. If I increase the number of classes a lot, then QGIS starts returning to colours that are very similar to previously used colours for other classes and the pattern is indiscernible.

If your plot shows 8 classes with 8 colours or even fewer, then I still can't replicate that. (In the case when I entered distances into the graph for any *pair of points* which are parts of the same *way*, it behaves more or less as expected.)

Here is a sketch of the code that I used when computing the physical distance between *every* pair of points and using this as edge weight. I loaded the points from OpenStreetMap into a Pandas DataFrame called `nodes` whose columns are `id`, `lat`, `lon`.

```
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas

from pyproj import Geod
geod = Geod(ellps="WGS84")

import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

'''
[...]
Here I load the points from my OSM data download into the Pandas DataFrame nodes.
[...]
'''

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes['id'])

edges = list()
#nr_nodes = 50
nr_nodes = len(G.nodes)
for i in range(nr_nodes):
    for j in range(i, nr_nodes):
        lons = [nodes.iloc[k]['lon'] for k in [i, j]]
        lats = [nodes.iloc[k]['lat'] for k in [i, j]]
        dist = geod.line_length(lons, lats)
        edges.append((nodes.iloc[i]['id'], nodes.iloc[j]['id'], {'weight': dist}))

G.add_edges_from(edges)
matrix = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
labeler = KMeans(n_clusters=8)
labeler.fit(matrix)

p_list = nodes.apply(lambda x: Point(x[2], x[1]), axis=1) # The list of points with lon, lat.
GraphShape = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(nodes['id'], geometry=p_list)

for (row, label) in enumerate(labeler.labels_):
    GraphShape.at[row, 'costcluster'] = label
GraphShape.to_file('graphShape8.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

My `graphShape8.geojson` looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "29587036", "costcluster": 2.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.9154778, 47.8702779 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "264508857", "costcluster": 2.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.9151344, 47.8706669 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "301435315", "costcluster": 2.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.9162008, 47.8698175 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "669212106", "costcluster": 2.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.9164004, 47.8696363 ] } },
...
```

Comment: Hey Bence thank you very much for that effort. It is good to see that my recipe works with your simpler data. And I think you are quite right that the problem comes from the weights on my edges. I meanwhile found a solution for my problem and will post it as the answer.